# how to force the processing order of Dojo sx:div

Tags: java, struts2, dojo

in my struts2 application i have a JSP wich include two dojo sx:div for ajax refreshing. During the rendering of the page, processing of sx:div there is an error because the first is process is one that appears second in the JSP. How can i force struts2 to process the first sx:div before ?

JSP file :

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="sx" uri="/struts-dojo-tags"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://displaytag.sf.net/el" prefix="display"%>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<s:url value="/js/ui.js" />"></script>

<s:form action="searchUpdateCollect.do" name="searchUpdateForm"
    id="searchUpdateFormId" theme="simple">

    <sx:div id="idDiv1" href="doFirstAction.do"
        formId="myFirstFormId" listenTopics="/updateFirstTopic"
        theme="ajax">
    </sx:div>


    <div class="contentTable">

        <sx:div id="idDiv2" href="doSecondAction.do"
            formId="MySecondFormId" listenTopics="/updateSecondTopic"
            afterNotifyTopics="/updateFirstTopic" theme="ajax">
        </sx:div>
    </div>
</s:form>
```

The actual process :

- when the JSP file is render the idDiv2 is process and the action methode doSecondAction is call
- the idDiv1 is process and the action methode doFirstAction is call

I want :
 - when the JSP file is render the idDiv1 is process and the action methode doFirstAction is call
 - the idDiv2 is process and the action methode dosecondAction is call

Comment: if you are using latest version of struts2, Please do not user dojo tags and they are deprecated and no longer supported. you can use either jquery plugin or simple DOJO

Comment: Ajax is calling asynchronous, if look at the abbreviation letters, what kind of behavior do you expect?